# I making custom shopify theme. On my homepage "Add section" is not available to me

Tags: shopify

I can programmatically add it to my page homepage by adding  {% section 'header-text' %}, but I want to add it through the "add section" GUI. I looked similar questions and I have  {{ content_for_index }} in my index.liquid and {% schema %} and {% endschema %}

Here is my code theme.liquid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ page_title }}</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}" />
        <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        {{ content_for_header }}
        <!-- Header hook for plugins -->
        {{
            "application.scss" | asset_url | stylesheet_tag
        }}
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="nav-holder">
                <a href="/" class="logo main"><h1>Dreamy Cream</h1></a>
                <div class="nav__button" id="burger">{% include 'icon-navicon' %}</div>
                <div class="nav-links" id="menu">
                    <ul class="nav-items">
                        {% for link in linklists.main-menu.links %} {% assign
                        child_list_handle = link.title | handleize %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    <a href="/cart" class="shopping-cart">{% include 'icon-cart' %}</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
             {% section 'header-text' %} 
    </header>
        <main role="main">
            {{ content_for_layout }}
        </main>
        {{ "application.js" | asset_url | script_tag }}
    </body>
</html>
```

header-text.liquid

```
<div class="nav__title main" id="{{section.settings.id}}">
    <h1>{{section.settings.title}}</h1>
</div>

{% schema %}
{
    "name": "opening text",
    "class": "opeaning-text-section",
    "settings": [
    {

        "id": "title",
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Section Title ",
        "default": "Taste the intensity" 

    }  
] ,
"presets": [
{
  "name": "Title Text",
  "category":"Store information"
}
]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I needed a section that was programmed in the theme.liquid  {% section 'header-text' %}

I found the solution https://github.com/Shopify/themekit/issues/842